# How include more response fields from API in my filter, ex: email

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's the code where I'd like to filter "email" and not only "name"

```
  useEffect(() => {
      const results = filtered.filter(
        (res) =>
          res.name.toLowerCase().includes(result)
  */I'd like to include res.email as well. */
   
      )
      setData(results);
    }, [result]);
    //console.log(data)
```

Comment: Use logical operators like `&&` for and.

Comment: I tried but it did not work. How would né rhe correct sintax?

Comment: Can you please add sample data of result and filtered so that it will be easier to answer this question and understand it, thanks.

Comment: I tried in this way but it did not work:  `useEffect(() => {
    const results = filtered.filter(
      (res) =>
      (res.name.toLowerCase()).includes(result.toLowerCase()) && res.email.toLowerCase().includes(results.toLowerCase())
    )

    setData(results);
  
  }, [result]);  `

Answer (score 0):

> You can try below:

```
useEffect(() => {
      const results = filtered.filter(
        (res) =>
          res.name.toLowerCase()).includes(result.toLowerCase() && res.email.toLowerCase().includes(email.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: It did not work. When I tried to filter nothing happens

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hi i believe you want result either includes name or email, if that is the case you can use this way..

```
useEffect(() => {
  const results = filtered.filter(
    (res) =>
      [res.name.toLowerCase(),res.email.toLowerCase()].includes(result)
  )
  setData(results);
}, [result]);
//console.log(data)
```

Comment: I tried your code, but unfortunately it did not work. When I filter in the search bar nothing happens. It just works  when using "name".

Comment: Can you please give sample data, for res and result so i can test it ?

Comment: I'm using this free API:  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", also I tried in this way but it did not work properly, please the this part of the code:  
  `useEffect(() => {
    const results = filtered.filter(
      (res) =>
        res.name.toLowerCase().includes(result) && res.email.toLowerCase().includes(result)

    )
    setData(results);
    console.log(result)
  }, [result]);  `